# Can't iterate over 2d array to normalize data

Tags: python

I'm trying to normalize my data and i need to iterate over the training and testing set. I tried in different ways but i get this error `list indices must be integers or slices, not list`. I've tried putting `range()` and `len()` but i still got the same error.

Code:

```
def minMaxNrom(training_data, testing_data):
    for i in training_data:
        for j in training_data:
            new_data = training_data[i][j] - min(j) / max(j) - min(j)    

    for i in testing_data:
        for j in testing_data:
            new_testing_data = testing_data[i][j] - min(j) / max(j) - min(j)


    return (new_data, new_testing_data)
```

Comment: why don't you just use MinMaxScaler from `sklearn.preprocessing`

Comment: @dexter It's college so they don't allow us to use libraries and want us to code it ourselves.

Comment: @TomKarzes I've tried that i also got an error. I also tried with `len` but i still got an error, that's why im confused.

Comment: @Stefan which uni wouldn't allow student's to use libraries?

Comment: @dexter I think they want us to learn how things work behind the libraries/code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using lists as indices. You may want to use enumerate. This will fix your error:

```
def minMaxNrom(training_data, testing_data):
    for indi, i in enumerate(training_data):
        for indj, j in enumerate(training_data):
            new_data = training_data[indi][indj] - min(j) / max(j) - min(j)

    for indi, i in enumerate(testing_data):
        for indj, j in enumerate(testing_data):
            new_testing_data = testing_data[indi][indj] - min(j) / max(j) - min(j)

    return (new_data, new_testing_data)
```

## Some guess work as to what you are trying to achieve

Without more information it is difficult to know why your code is failing after fixing the `can't use list as index` problem, but here is my guess:

```
def minMaxNrom(training_data, testing_data):
    new_data = []
    new_testing_data = []
    for indi, i in enumerate(training_data):
        for indj, j in enumerate(training_data):
            new_data.append((training_data[indi][indj] - min(j)) / (max(j) - min(j)))

    for indi, i in enumerate(testing_data):
        for indj, j in enumerate(testing_data):
            new_testing_data.append((testing_data[indi][indj] - min(j)) / (max(j) - min(j)))

    return (new_data, new_testing_data)
```

## Explanation

Say you have:

```
training_data = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [4, 4, 4]]
for i in training_data:
    print(i)
```

This will print:

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 4, 4]
```

As you can see, the `i` here is each sublist. But to access these sublists with reference, you do:

```
print(training_data[0])  # gives first sublist
print('---')
print(training_data[1])  # gives second sublist
print('---')
print(training_data[2])  # gives third sublist
```

This will give:

```
[1, 2]
---
[3, 4, 5]
---
[4, 4, 4]
```

Note that to access these sublists we use a number as the index not a list (which is what you were using). So in order to access each list and get its index, we use enumerate (a better variable name for `i` would be `sublist`):

```
for indi, i in enumerate(training_data):
    print('indi: ', indi)
    print('i: ', i)
    print('training_data[indi]: ', training_data[indi])
    print('---')
```

this gives:

```
indi:  0
i:  [1, 2]
training_data[indi]:  [1, 2]
---
indi:  1
i:  [3, 4, 5]
training_data[indi]:  [3, 4, 5]
---
indi:  2
i:  [4, 4, 4]
training_data[indi]:  [4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Can i ask why are you using `indi, i` and `indj, j` instead of only one?

Comment: Updated answer to answer comment.

Comment: Thank you for the amazing explanation. I want to ask now why does my index go out of range?

Comment: Are you talking about a new error after using integer indices? One way that the function can fail is if `training_data` (or `testing_data`) is empty, e.i `testing_data = []`. Another way the function can fail is if your sublists are empty, e.i `testing_data = [[1,2,3],[3,4], []]` (note the third empty sublist). Your `max()` and `min()` functions will fail on empty lists, you can set default values to `max()` and `min()` in the case of an empty list. For what input is the function failing?

Comment: Updated further.

Comment: Looks like I need to learn how to use `()` appropriately thank you.

Comment: Not only that, but in the updated version you are appending to a list. With what you were using originally, you were throwing away all new data and just keeping/returning the last. I did not fix that originally since you mentioned this is school work, which means it is best if you get deep into debugging.