# Getting back a tuple when trying to normalize training data

Tags: python

I have a training and testing set. I need to normalize them but i can't seem to iterate over them i get this error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`. I will give a small part of the set just so you can see how it is structured. I've tried with `enumerate` and `range` but i get the same error.

```
training_data = [
    [3.6216, 8.6661, -2.8073, -0.44699, 0],
    [4.5459, 8.1674, -2.4586, -1.4621, 0],
    [3.866, -2.6383, 1.9242, 0.10645, 0],
    [3.4566, 9.5228, -4.0112, -3.5944, 0],
    [0.32924, -4.4552, 4.5718, -0.9888, 0],
    [4.3684, 9.6718, -3.9606, -3.1625, 0],
    [3.5912, 3.0129, 0.72888, 0.56421, 0],
    [2.0922, -6.81, 8.4636, -0.60216, 0],
]
```

Code:

```
def minMaxNrom(training_data, testing_data):
    for i in enumerate(training_data):
        for j in enumerate(training_data):
            new_data = training_data[i][j] - min(j) / max(j) - min(j)    

    for i in enumerate(testing_data):
        for j in enumerate(testing_data[i]):
            new_testing_data = testing_data[i][j] - min(j) / max(j) - min(j)


    return (new_data, new_testing_data)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't iterate over 2d array to normalize data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56388270/cant-iterate-over-2d-array-to-normalize-data)

Comment: @Perplexabot Yes you commented there too and i solved it briefly but I still got stuck with `'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: You fixed that problem, why are you posting it again? At least post an updated version with your new error.

Comment: One problem is that the command `enumerate` gives you an iterations count as well as a straight list element, both of which are in variable i. Hence in this case you'll need to separate the count from the list element. I think the code has another bug as @Perplexabot identifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for i in enumertae(list)` generate a `tuple`, ie `(index:value)`, what you are looking for is index, so use `for i,v in enumerate(list)`

```
def minMaxNrom(training_data, testing_data):
    for i,v1 in enumerate(training_data):
        for j,v2 in enumerate(v1):
            new_data = training_data[i][j] - (min(v1) / max(v1)) - min(v1)    

    for i,v1 in enumerate(testing_data):
        for j,v2 in enumerate(v1):
            new_testing_data = testing_data[i][j] - (min(v1) / max(v1)) - min(v1)

    return (new_data, new_testing_data)
```

Comment: I've tried this but now i get `'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: On what line of the code you posted is that error occurring?